# How do you get user input from a button using ActionListener? Java

Tags: java

This is just a code for a GUI with a button.  How do you make it count the number of clicks using ActionListener?  Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Xyz extends JFrame {
    public Xyz() {
        super("");
        setSize(500, 500);
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout();
        setLayout(grid);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("Press");
        add(button);
        setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xyz z = new Xyz();
    }
}
```

Comment: Set up a "count" variable, each time the `button`'s `ActionListener` is triggered, update then "count" variable

Comment: How do you use an if loop?  What is the syntax for if clicked, then count++?